# Sum of prime and non prime number is what?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If $p$ is prime and $q$ is not prime and they are positive, what can you say about the $p+q$, can you get every natural greater then 2?

Comment: How do you get $5$?

Comment: the non prime number can be 0

Comment: Each number larger than $3$ that is neither $p$ nor $2p$ for some prime $p$ can be reached (call it $n$, take $p$ to some prime divisor of $n$ and $q=n-p$). If $p > 5$ is a prime number, $p=3+(p-3)$, $p-3 > 2$ and not even. If $p > 2$, $2p=2+(2p-2)$, $2p-2 \geq 4$ is even.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p=3$. Then $q$ can be any even number greater than $2$, so you get all the odd numbers greater than $5$.

If $n > 6$ is even then (as @lulu comments) one of $q = n-3, n-5, n-7$ is divisible by $3$, so not prime. Then $n = q + $ a prime.

You can check the small cases by hand.

Comment: i still dont get it. What set of numbers can you make? in one case all the odds > 5 and in the other all the non primes > 6?

Comment: The second case covers all the evens $n > 6$. Then $n= 3 + (n-3)$ or $5 + (n-5)$ or $7 + (n-7)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n$ be a natural number greater then $5$. If $n$ is odd, then $n - 3$ is even and since $n >5$ $n-3$ is not a prime. If $n$ is even, $n - 2$ is even and thus not a prime since $n > 4$.

The exceptional cases $3, 4, 5$ can easily be solved by hand:
$$3 = 2 + 1$$
$$4 = 3 + 1$$
and $5$ does not have such a decomposition.